# Nested objects causing lost memory "leak" in .NET 4 LinkedList

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, linked-list, dispose

Edit: Please ignore this question, this is a PBCAK programmer error.

**Part 1**

How can I correct the memory leak in this code?

**Part 2**

If the solution includes adding `Dispose` to `SummaryEntity`, how should I dispose of the object if I have a second list (summary-of-summaries) that references it?   Assume I want to keep the 10 most recent `SummaryEntities` in the summary-of-summaries

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace TestDoesLinkedListLeak
{
    public class SummaryEntity
    {
        public object PlaceHolder { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Note: This is a Field instead of a Property to support Interlockd methods
        /// </summary>
        public int ReferenceCount;
        public int Value;
        public int? PreviousValue { get; set; }
    }
    class FrequencyOfMatchedHash : Dictionary<int, SummaryEntity> 
    {
        private object frequencyOfMatchedHashLock;

        public void AddRecordHash(int hashCode, int value, object placeHolder)
        {
            SummaryEntity se = null;
            try
            {
                se = new SummaryEntity();
                se.ReferenceCount = 1;
                se.PlaceHolder = placeHolder;
                se.Value = value;

                lock (this.frequencyOfMatchedHashLock)
                {
                    if (this.ContainsKey(hashCode))
                    {
                        System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(ref this[hashCode].Value, value);
                        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref  this[hashCode].ReferenceCount);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Add(hashCode, se);
                    }
                }

                //this.AddOrUpdate(hashCode, se ,
                // (k, v) => 
                //     {
                //         System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(ref v.Value , value);
                //         System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref v.ReferenceCount); 
                //         return v;
                //     });
            }
            finally
            {
                //se.Dispose();

            }
        }
    }
    class LLDateNode //:IDisposable
    {
        public FrequencyOfMatchedHash FrequencyOfMatch { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Date + " Count:" + FrequencyOfMatch.Count;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start");
                Console.WriteLine("Total Memory: {0}  Forced Collect: {1}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false), GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
                LinkedList<LLDateNode> tmp = new LinkedList<LLDateNode>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 111111; i++)
                {
                   // Console.Write(".");
                    tmp.AddFirst(new LLDateNode() { Date = DateTime.UtcNow, FrequencyOfMatch = new FrequencyOfMatchedHash() });
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Done create, now delete");
                Console.WriteLine("Total Memory: {0}  Forced Collect: {1}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false), GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
                Console.WriteLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Console.Write("x");
                    tmp.RemoveFirst();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("End of program");
                Console.WriteLine("Total Memory: {0}  Forced Collect: {1}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false), GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
start
Total Memory: 186836  Forced Collect: 106656

Done create, now delete
Total Memory: 11222752  Forced Collect: 11217844


End of program
Total Memory: 11226036  Forced Collect: 5662320
```

Comment: @EugenRieck I shouldn't have posted the Property `ReferenceCount`. It's an extract from a in-development application.  `More info not immediately relevant to this question`: I have a dictionary (not listed here) that tracks objects by hashcode, and a linked list to track objects by date.  As objects age out of the linked list, I remove them from the dictionary.  The dictionary is more or less a summary and rolling aggregate of a point in time.  Reference count is the sum of all linked list items that are "active" and included in the Summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, however I think that when you are calling the `tmp.RemoveFirst()` the size of `tmp.Count` becomes smaller while the `i` keeps growing. So, you're only removing half of the `Dictionary`. Either don't increment the `i` or place the `tmp.Count` into a variable then use that in the loop condition. Considering the size of your last Force Collect is around half, this looks like it could be your issue.

Comment: You're right.  I am trying to repro a memory leak in my app and am having issues.. I thought I had zeroed in on the issue, back to the drawing board.